# Magento 2 checkout page not working with error of SSL

Tags: checkout, https

plz advice any one how we can force https

when i add product it work fine.. cart page also work fine .. but checkout page says loading and loading.. and error https

my website

http://muzikhausberlin.de

Answer (score 0):

to force HTTPS, change your base url to `https://`.

```
bin/magento setup:store-config:set --base-url="https://muzikhausberlin.de/"
bin/magento setup:store-config:set --base-url-secure="https://muzikhausberlin.de/"
bin/magento setup:store-config:set --use-secure=1
bin/magento setup:store-config:set --use-secure-admin=1
bin/magento cache:flush
```

also if you have some redirect issues, you can add this to apache or .htaccess config:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !=https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: thanks let me check if work. i'll update you in few hour